# Вопрос по параллельной работе socket

Tags: python, сокет

У меня несколько скриптов на Python, использующие модуль socket, все они крутятся на одном компе. Если их запустить сразу несколько, то данные поступают с задержкой, если запущен один то работа идет нормально.

Мне напели про то, что где-то после импорта socket можно и нужно указывать параллельную обработку сокета, но никто не удосужился объяснить :(

Как с этим бороться?
Есть ли другие варианты?

### upd:

HOST и PORT взяты условно, сервер находится не на одном компе с клиентом

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
HOST = '1.1.1.10'
PORT = 777

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
def connect_to_server():
    print 'Установка соединения с сервером', HOST+':', PORT
    try :
        sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
    except Exception, e:
        print 'Соединение не установлено, причина:', e
        sys.exit(0)
    print 'Соединение установленно'
connect_to_server()
...
#работа скрипта бла бла бла
result = sock.recv(1024)
print result
...
```

### udp2:

после мониторинга пакетов выяснилось , что пакеты приходят "вовремя", а сам скрипт их обрабатывает с задержкой

со временем это доходит до абсурда ... 2 и более минуты

в самом скрипте есть несколько потоков, используются очереди (Queue), подключение к 2 БД ...

### udp3:

Скрипты запускались на разных ОС, эфект одинаковый

ОС:Fedora 16, Ubuntu 11.04

Comment: Судя по 1.1.1.10 с внешним. Вопрос в другом. Вы уверены, что сервер нормально поддерживает несколько параллельных соединений по одному и тому же порту ? Надо смотреть ситуацию с обеих сторон.

Comment: @ReinRaus, Вы тоже считаете, что надо смотреть на серверную часть ? С догадкой про 777 можно согласиться, а можно считать, что и HOST и PORT условные. Ждем ответов от ТС.

Comment: да, HOST и PORT условные... с стороны сервера все проверили, промониторили, сервер отдает информацию в туже секунду как получает, а вот на стороне клиента вылез интересный момент - физически инфа заходит в одно время, а судя по логам обрабатывается позже

Comment: да, пробовал запускать на Fedora 16, Ubuntu 11.04

Comment: В каком месте скрипта

    со временем это доходит до абсурда ... 2 и более минуты

это происходит ? Новый connect проходит до завершения скрипта с предыдущим ? или висит на sock.recv или где ?

Если ждет connect, то можно предположить, что не установлена SO_REUSEADDR опция сокета.

Comment: это отличие времени физического входа пакета (я сниферил это дело) с временем в логах работы скрипта, временной штамп ставится когда в цикле одного из потоков выполняется обработка Queue'ов. 

ЗЫ

Все это происходит за одно открытое соединение сокета, то есть после открытия соединения он не закрывается, а в потоке происходит свой специфический обмен пингами ибо сервер закроет это соединение со своей стороны насильно.

Comment: Как вариант: сервер обрабатывает подключение какой-то synchronized функцией и поэтому остальные потоки ожидают конца обработки. Расскажите подробнее про сервер.

Comment: Дело не в сервере, с него на мою сетевую(судя по информации с снифера) все приходит вовремя.

ЗЫ
Я добавил себе дебаги на проверку когда клиент получил информацию с сокета и когда он ее обработал.

ЗЫЫ

Еще я читал про то что сама ОС может буферизовать то что получила и постепенно мне выдавать. Но если сделать сокет не блокируемым(sock.setblocking(0)), то нужно уметь контролировать есть ли что то на сокете или нет, а я пока не умею... 

ладно, подождем логов там видно будет ...

Comment: Приведите уже код сервера, незачем гадать на кофейной гуще.

И многозначительные `...` в листинге тоже смущают.

Answer (score 1):

Перепишите клиент с использованием [asyncore](http://wiki.python.su/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B/Network/asyncore) или [Twisted](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/94397/).
В основе обоих модулей лежит система событий, то есть Вы пишите callback-функции для тех или иных событий в сокете.

### Минимум усилий Вы затратите переделывая на asyncore.

**UPD**
Небольшой тест привел к выводам:
Все написанное выше неверно, ассинхронные модули не помогут.
Копайте в сторону сервера.
Копайте в сторону не закрытия соединения сервером или клиентом, поэтому все так долго- соединение закрывается по таймауту. Я поначалу в конце запроса всего один раз написал `\r\n` и потом долго втыкал, почему 20 секунд обрабатывается запрос.
Следующий код максимально одновременно пытается обратиться к локальному серверу.

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import socket, time, threading
class unit(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, delay, numThread, startTime):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.delay=delay
        self.daemon=True
        self.times=[]
        self.numThread=numThread
        self.startTime=startTime
    def run(self):
        while self.delay-time.time()>2.: time.sleep(1)
        while self.delay-time.time()>0: pass
        self.timestamp()
        sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.timestamp()
        sock.connect(("localhost", 80))
        self.timestamp()
        sock.send("GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n")
        self.timestamp()
        sock.recv(1024)
        self.timestamp()
        f=open('/var/www/temp'+str(self.numThread), 'w')
        f.write(str(self.times))
        f.close()
        endThread(self.numThread)
    def timestamp(self):
        self.times+=[time.time()-self.startTime]

def endThread(num):
    global count
    del count[num]

count={}
print 1
startTime=time.time()
for i in range(0, 10):
    unit(int(startTime+10), i, startTime).start()
    count[i]=1
while len(count)>0: time.sleep(.1)
```

Результат (объединение 10 файлов в порядке номеров):

```
[9.720899105072021, 9.72108793258667, 9.72229790687561, 9.723675966262817, 9.723704099655151]
[9.721373081207275, 9.721570014953613, 9.723891973495483, 9.725044012069702, 9.725055932998657]
[9.721120119094849, 9.721139907836914, 9.722417116165161, 9.723730087280273, 9.723743915557861]
[9.72129201889038, 9.721333980560303, 9.722399950027466, 9.723694086074829, 9.723835945129395]
[9.721221923828125, 9.72124195098877, 9.722342014312744, 9.723649978637695, 9.723757982254028]
[9.721265077590942, 9.721699953079224, 9.724746942520142, 9.724776983261108, 9.725917100906372]
[9.72160792350769, 9.721628904342651, 9.7239830493927, 9.724015951156616, 9.725088119506836]
[9.721718072891235, 9.721736907958984, 9.725368022918701, 9.72540807723999, 9.72588300704956]
[9.721158981323242, 9.721179008483887, 9.725352048873901, 9.725423097610474, 9.726080894470215]
[9.720865964889526, 9.721676111221313, 9.72466492652893, 9.724700927734375, 9.725841999053955]
```

Comment: Со стороны сервера проблем нет, я нашел, где зарыта собака :)

Вся проблема в модуле обработки очередей (from Queue import Queue), информация ложится туда достаточно быстро, а вот выгружается очень медленно, пока непонятно по какой причине. Возможно из-за того, что загрузка в очередь и выгрузка из нее происходит одновременно.