# Русскоязычная литература/документация по Twisted?

Tags: python, twisted

Кто нибудь встречал русскоязычную литературу/документацию по Twisted?

Comment: было бы круто еще какие-нибудь проекты посмотреть опенсорсные на твистеде. Если кто знает что-нибудь не монструозное и документированное дайте ссылку.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

пока нашел вот это :

- [Введение в асинхронное программирование и Twisted](http://ninaevseenko.github.com/async_twisted_ru/)
- В книге (Ноа Гифт, Джереми М. Джонс - Python в системном администрировании UNIX и Linux) есть примеры работ с Twisted'ом (209 страница)

На инглише:

- [тут](http://slav0nic.org.ua/static/books/python/) нашел книгу (O'Reilly,.Twisted.Network.Programming.Essentials.(2005).DDU.LotB.chm), перевода я найти не смог